# Estoy realizando un buscador php sql y me aparece el siguiente error: Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

estoy intentando realizar un buscador con PHP y SQL, me esta lanzando un error que la verdad no entiendo a que se deba y es el siguiente:

> mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given

Mi código: index.php

```
<?php
mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","testing") or die ("DB Error");
$output = '';
//collect

if(isset($_POST['search'])){
    $searchq = $_POST['search'];
    $searchq = preg_replace ("#[^0-9a-z]#i", "", $searchq);
    
    $query = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE title LIKE '%$searchq%'") or die ("error del query");
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($query);
    if ($count == 0){
        $output = 'No se han encontrado resultados!';
    } else {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
            $tname = $row['title'];
            
            $output .= '<div>'.$tname.'</div>';
        }
    }
}

?>


 <div class="search">
    
      <button onclick="show_hide()" class="searchButton">
        <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
        </button>
     <form action="index.php" method="post">
      <input type="text" id="input" name="search" class="searchTerm" placeholder="Buscar anime..."/>

       </form>

</div>
```

He estado revisando y todo esta escrito correctamente con respecto a la base de datos.

Buscador:
[image: IMAGEN]

Error:
[image: IMAGEN]

Base de datos:
[image: IMAGEN]

[image: IMAGEN]

Comment: A esta función `mysqli_query` pásale como primer argumento la conexión

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mysqli_query() utiliza 2 parametros, el primero es la conexión y el segundo la consulta.

Que haría yo:

1. La conexión guardarla en una variable:

```
$link= mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","testing") or die ("DB Error");
```

2. corregir la linea del Query

```
$query = mysqli_query($link ,"SELECT * FROM posts WHERE title LIKE '%$searchq%'") or die ("error del query");
```

Fuente:
https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.query.php

Comment: De igual manera utilizando el paradicma de objetos se me hace mas facil utilizar la base de datos. $mysqli = new mysqli("ejemplo.com", "usuario", "contraseña", "basedatos");... a lo mejor se te hace mas amable.